# Pi revision did not recognize a52082 picar

Tags: pi-3

The command is:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ picar
```

The result is a [Errno 121] Remote I/O

Comment: What is `picar`?  What do you expect to happen?  Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @Paul, (1) PiCar uses I2C PCA9685 PWM module.  (2)  [Errno 121] Remote I/O almost always means I2C transceiving problem. (3) Use i2cdetect -y 1 to make sure PCA9685 is still detected. (4) Use python to ping or write read PCA9685 registers, (5) Reference: https://www.sunfounder.com/picar-s-kit.html

Comment: @Paul，You must read the user manual very carefully, before you know how to do (1) and (2) below:  (1) Use Rpi-Config or GUI Desktop to enable I2C (Or you will get the I/O error you mention in your question! :), (2) Using i2ctools to detect PCA9685 (3) More References: 

(a) https://www.sunfounder.com/learn/download/UGlDYXItU19Vc2VyX01hbnVhbC5wZGY=/dispi

(b) https://github.com/sunfounder/SunFounder_PiCar-S/tree/master/example

(c) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rgibVl-CBt8

(d) https://github.com/sunfounder/SunFounder_PiCar-S

Have fun! :) Cheers.

Comment: @Paul, Your question starts with "Pi Revision".  I guess your old Pi works but new revision does not work.  PiCar works for Rpi3 python 3.5.  If you have revised to Rpi4 and Python 3.7, some of the drivers might not work. You might like to go to SunFounder forum to confirm.

Comment: SunFounder PiCar V User Manual
https://www.sunfounder.com/learn/download/U21hcnRfVmlkZW9fQ2FyX1YyLjBfZm9yX1Jhc3BiZXJyeV9QaV9QaUNhci1WXy5wZGY=/dispi

Comment: picar is a SunFounder "Smart Sensor Car Kit" for Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I agree that my problem is associated with I2C. I followed the manual. "dtparam=i2c_arm=on" was added to config.txt is not enough. I will try the other suggestions.

Comment: The software will control the front wheels of the PiCar robot.

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.16.

Comment: I thank you all and am sorry that I did not comment sooner. I reset my account in order to logon.

Comment: You'll need to open an issue at https://github.com/sunfounder/SunFounder_PiCar/issues as their code doesn't work for ANY model of RPi4B

Comment: `sudo i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- `

Comment: Regardless, I am still getting: `
pi@Car1:~ $ sudo picar
[Errno 121] Remote I/O error
Error. Pi revision didn't recognize, module number: a52082
Exiting...`

Comment: I read the manual carefully and watched videos. I followed the step in this one, **SunFounder PiCar Kit V2.0 for Raspberry Pi Assembly**. It mimics the manual.

Comment: I receive the following warning from the sunfounder.com website: **This connection is not private.** I did not open any sunfounder websites.

Comment: I am using **Raspberry Pi 3 Model B**.

Comment: The manual gave the impression and YouTube gave the impression that the Pi did not have to be connected to the partially built robot. It does!